# Div innerHTML is not updated

Tags: javascript

I have the following test code and I want to update the div text and show one, two, three... but the result is only the last

Edit: Because any answer here it depends on "sleep", I don't actually use "sleep" on my code. I replaced the code with a for loop.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <button onclick="test()" id="myBtn">test</button><br />
  <div id="demo"></div>
  <script>
    function dosomething() {
      for(i=1; i<=500; i++) console.log(i);
    }

    function test() {
      let $myBtn = document.getElementById('myBtn');
      $myBtn.style.display = 'none';

      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 'one';
      dosomething();
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 'two';
      dosomething();
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 'three';
      dosomething();
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 'stop';

      $myBtn.style.display = 'block';
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It's because you're overriding the current inner HTML with the new value. Use the string concatenation (`+=`) operator instead.

Comment: Please do some research, why these kind “sleep” function implementations are a really bad thing to do in JavaScript. And then go read up on how to use setInterval/setTimeout.

Comment: The Browser will do: 1) run the javascript interpreter 2) render
and you force him by the sleep command to stay in the javascript interpreter.

Comment: Thanks for reply guys! I don't want to append the text and the result becomes "onetwothreestop" I want to show the first text which is "one", after that show the text "two" and so.... CBroe the "sleep" is just an example to show the problem. I have other code written in "sleeps" that creates elements loading data from db, and many more

Answer (score 2):

In your example the system never has a chance to show you the one, two, three because it's tied up looping in your while and the page is not getting repainted.

You need to give it a break!

You can use the JS function setInterval for this - it will run a given function every time interval. But you also need to know when to stop it - and it's not absolutely accurate as there may be other things going on on your system so don't use it for e.g. implementing a stopwatch.

You can also use the JS function setTimeout which runs just the once, and then you run it again etc until you've output all the texts. Here's a small example:

```html
<html>
<body>
<button onclick="test()" id="myBtn">test</button><br />
<div id="demo"></div>
<script>
let text = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'stop'];
let i = 0; //this indicates which text we are on
function test() {
  
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text[i];
  i++;
  if ( i< text.length) {
    setTimeout(test,1000);
  }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be better off using the in-built `setTimeout` function, with some tweaks. Something like:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <button onclick="test()" id="myBtn">test</button><br />
    <div id="demo"></div>
    <script>
    var contentArray = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'stop'];   // <- declare the array of values you want here
    function test() {
      let $myBtn = document.getElementById('myBtn');
      
      $myBtn.style.display = 'none';

      for(let i = 0; i < contentArray.length; i++){   // <- using 'let' instead of 'var', so a new variable is created on each iteration
        setTimeout(function() {
          // console.log(i);    // <- if you want to see the values, uncomment this line
          document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = contentArray[i];

        }, 1000 * (i+1));
      };
      
      $myBtn.style.display = 'block';
    }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

With your self written sleep function, you stopped the Browser from passing the rendering Process until all your code had run.
You have to do something like this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <button onclick="test()" id="myBtn">test</button><br />
  <div id="demo"></div>
  <script>
    function sleep(sleepDurationMS) {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                resolve();
            }, sleepDurationMS);
        });
    }

    function test() {
      let $myBtn = document.getElementById('myBtn');
      $myBtn.style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 'one';
      sleep(1000).then(() => {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 'two';
        sleep(1000).then(() => {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 'three';
            sleep(1000).then(() => {
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 'stop';
                $myBtn.style.display = 'block';
              });
          });
      });
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Yes Rene I know that will work. But I don't have actually sleep on my code. Between "one" and "two" I have code to read data from db ~800ms. Between "two" and "three" I have code to create elements on document for db data ~1-2sec. Between "three" and "stop" I have append text on elements that created and got it through a websocket ... and more. And The innerHTML it is not updated. Maybe is wrong my question

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is Asynchronous so you will Get 'stop' as output .
Here I am using setTimeout Function() .
You don't need sleep function and here.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>

  <body>
      <button onclick="test()" id="myBtn">test</button><br />
      <div id="demo"></div>
     <script>


  function test() {
   let $myBtn = document.getElementById('myBtn');
   $myBtn.style.display = 'none';

  
   setTimeout(function () {document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 'one';},1000);
   setTimeout(function () {document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 'two';},2000);
   setTimeout(function () {document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 'three';},3000);
   setTimeout(function () {document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 'stop';},4000);

  $myBtn.style.display = 'block';
   }
  </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `sleep` function is blocking the [Event Loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop) and this line

```
  $myBtn.style.display = 'none';
```

causes the text to be hidden.

If you want that `sleep` feature, you should write it in `async` manner using [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/vi/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) with [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <body>
    <button onclick="test()" id="myBtn">test</button><br />
    <div id="demo"></div>
    <script>
      const sleep = async (sleepDurationMS) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() =>
        resolve(), sleepDurationMS))

      async function test() {
        let $myBtn = document.getElementById('myBtn');

        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 'one';
        await sleep(1000);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 'two';
        await sleep(1000);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 'three';
        await sleep(1000);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 'stop';

      }

    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: I don't have actually sleep on my code. Between "one" and "two" I have code to read data from db ~800ms. Between "two" and "three" I have code to create elements on document for db data ~1-2sec. Between "three" and "stop" I have append text on elements that created and got it through a websocket ... and more. And The innerHTML it is not updated. Maybe is wrong my question

Comment: If we remove the sleep and replace it with ```for(i=1; i<=10000; i++) console.log(i);``` the result will be the same